# What is the actual role of Node.PROPAGATE in AQS?

Tags: java

The `Node.PROPAGATE` state of the AQS inner class `Node` is only used in shared mode, but it causes the same behavior when `node.waitStatus` is 0. Will the successor node cycle more than once, then does he have more practical uses besides distinguishing between the two modes?

```
    private void doReleaseShared() {

    for (;;) {
        Node h = head;
        if (h != null && h != tail) {
            int ws = h.waitStatus;
            if (ws == Node.SIGNAL) {
                if (!h.compareAndSetWaitStatus(Node.SIGNAL, 0))
                    continue;            // loop to recheck cases
                unparkSuccessor(h);
            }
            else if (ws == 0 &&
                     !h.compareAndSetWaitStatus(0, Node.PROPAGATE))
                continue;                // loop on failed CAS
        }
        if (h == head)                   // loop if head changed
            break;
    }
}
```

My question is generated here.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: I updated the question and added the code.

Answer (score 1):

waitStatus value Node.PROPAGATE can only set for head node. Just indicate that the succeed node of head node will propagate unpark succeed node behavior. Because the succeed node maybe takes share lock successfully when current node take share lock successfully.